# If I uninstall Internet services - will IUSR user will be removed?

Tags: windows-xp, iis, iis-6

If I uninstall the Interent Services on an XP machine, will the relevant IUSR be deleted?

I can't think of a reason for it to stay, but want to be sure before I do anything.

Comment: It shouldn't be deleted, but you should backup any important files, connected to the user profile just incase.

Comment: not sure, I am talking about the anonymous Internet user that is created.